# Xammp showing me an error

Tags: xampp

Xammp showing me an error i have reinstall it again but still shows me an error[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Post taken from here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/491629/how-to-install-php-mbstring-extension-in-ubuntu/491631